# Easiest way to fail pipeline in Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data factory pipeline that has an "If Condition" Activity and I want the pipeline to fail on a certain condition. What is the best way to achieve this? There is no fail activity..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They've just added a "Fail Activity" in Data Factory and Synapse Analytics:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-fail-activity

It's found in the "General" category in "Activities" in the Data Factory Studio.

Comment: Useful new activity.

Comment: If you don't see the "Fail Activity", it may be because it's not yet available in your Azure region. (My region is US East.)

Answer (score 2):

**Update September 2021: There is now a [Fail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-fail-activity?) activity in ADF.**

First of all, please vote for this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/2d90df95-7226-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c). This is a common need.

There are several workarounds such as a Web Activity to throw an error by trying to connect to https://ThrowAnError or a Stored Procedure activity which executes a `raiserror` function in Azure SQL Database. But that’s as close as we can get to solving your problem currently.