# How to explicitly fail azure data factory pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any method to explicitly fail an azure data factory pipeline?

Comment: What do you mean `explicitly fail ` ? You want to view the fail log?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an Activity that would cause the pipeline to fail or terminate based on some condition. This does not currently exist, but I know it's been requested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to fail pipeline in Data Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341935/easiest-way-to-fail-pipeline-in-data-factory)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to fail your pipeline explicitly, one possible way is to have an invalid URL in your web activity which will fail the Web activity, which inturn will result in your pipeline to fail.

There is an existing feature request related to the same requirement in ADF user voice forum suggested by other ADF users. I would recommend you please up-vote and/or comment on this feedback which will help to increase the priority of the feature request implementation.

ADF User voice feedback related to this requirement: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38143873-a-new-activity-for-cancelling-the-pipeline-executi

**Additional info**:
In case if you just want to cancel your pipeline run then you can have a Web activity which calls the below REST API to cancel the pipeline run by using the pipelinerunID (you can get this value by using dynamic expression - @pipeline().RunId)

REST API to Cancel the Pipeline Run: POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/cancel?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/pipelineruns/%7BrunId%7D/cancel?api-version=2018-06-01)

MS Doc related to Rest API: [ADF Pipeline Runs - Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/cancel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried canceling the pipeline using the REST API? I am trying and my pipeline cannot find itself to cancel.

Comment: It turns out it was because DF cannot cancel when runing the pipeline in the debug mode. When I triggered it, it worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

Just set a variable with `@string(div(1, 0))`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends at which level you would like to stop the operation. For example at MSSQL DB operation, from SP you may RAISERROR above level 18 to raise an exception. As already stated incase of web Activity, request a non existent URL. That would also stop the process